# Devise redirect_url per controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to change the redirect_url that Devise uses on a per controller basis, i.e.:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :failure_url => admin_login_path
end
```

I don't want to change how admins are authorized.  I don't want to create an Admin model (devise_for :admin) or a customer failure app.  I want the same functionality across controllers except for the redirect_url after an authentication failure.

All input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but it seems that if you monkey patch a protected method called `redirect_url` in `class Devise::FailureApp`, and make it return an url based on some logic, then you can redirect to other URLs. The problem is, that the FailureApp is completely decoupled from your controller, so you'll have to use something to pass this information, such as singleton with controllers->failure_urls map.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CanCan to achieve

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash[:error] = exception.message
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Here's the [full example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-CanCan-+-Devise,-The-easy-way.).  This is also detailed in the [CanCan Wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Exception-Handling).  Good luck!